# Implementar cronometro en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa para adivinar la palabra, hay una función que va bajando los segundos que van pasando, pero me imprime una linea nueva incluso usando \r, además el cronometro se queda en 1 y no funciona mas, y el input tampoco funciona, tengo entendido que hay que usar thread para ejecutar funciones de forma paralera pero el programa no funciona

```
import time
import threading
import random

global t
t = 15

words = ["Hello", "House", "Keyboard", "Mouse", "Golang", "Python", "Java", "Computer", "Kernel", "Linux", "Windows"]


def generate_rword() -> str:
    r = random.randint(0, len(words))

    w = words[r]

    return w

word = generate_rword()


def tinput():
    global t
    while t != 0:
        n = input("\nWord ->:")

        if n == word:
            print("Correct word")
            exit(1)

    time.sleep(0.5)

def mainloop():
    global t
    while t != 0:

        print(f"\nTime: {t}", end="\r", flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)

        t = t - 1

    exit(1)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=mainloop)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=tinput)

t1.start()
t2.start()


t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que uses 2 tareas asincronas: Una para manejar el cronómetro y otra para la entrada de usuario. La parte asíncrona terminará cuando una de las 2 tareas finalice.

Como te dijeron en el comentario, hacer que la entrada de usuario refresque el conteo en pantalla a medida que escribes, todo en tiempo real, es muy complicado de hacer en la consola. Para ello mejor usa Tkinter, Wx, Qt, etc.

El siguiente ejemplo tiene como referencia [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74103173/1545868) (en inglés). Usa el módulo aioconsole `pip install aioconsole` para tener una entrada de usuario asincrona.
Es posible hacer una entrada asíncrona sin librerías, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326191/1545868) y [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76183977/1545868), pero eso lo debes investigar más a fondo.

```python
import asyncio
from aioconsole import ainput

async def user_input():
    io_user = await ainput("Escriba algo: ")
    return io_user

async def timeout():
    await asyncio.sleep(10) # Espera 10 segundos
    return None

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(user_input())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(timeout())
    resp = await asyncio.wait({task1, task2}, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    
    result = None
    for done in resp[0]:
        result = done.result()
    
    if result != None:
        print(f'Escribiste: {result}')
    else:
        print()
        print('Qué lástima, se acabó el tiempo')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Si, la verdad se me esta complicando, usare Tkinter